# SQL to identify where all three required fields are not populated

Tags: sql

Need an SQL statement for:
If one of the date fields is populated then all three need to be populated from these three fields.

Table:

ID| **Start_Date| Middle_Date|End_Date**|Licence

So as an example:

If ID 1 HAS **Start Date**, NO **Middle Date**, NO **End Date** and has Licence then this should show up in the result.

If ID 2 HAS **Start Date**, HAS **Middle Date** but NO **End Date** and has Licence then this should show up in the result.

If ID 3 has NO **Start Date**, NO **Middle Date** but NO **End Date** and has Licence then this should NOT show up in the result.

If ID 4 HAS **Start Date**, HAS **Middle Date** HAS **End Date** and has Licence then this should NOT show up in the result.

If ID 5 HAS **Start Date**, NO **Middle Date** but HAS **End Date** and has Licence then this should show up in the result.

Comment: how to populate? What's the criteria ..?

Comment: Try researching for `Coalesce` function

Comment: @pran86 Its better to share the sample output you are expecting, so that everyone is clear about the requirement

Comment: added with examples. thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @pran86 please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Below query will help you :

```
select *
from tablename
where (start_date is not null or middle_date is not null or end_date is not null) and 
      (start_date is null or middle_date is null or end_date is null);
```

The above query will return all the queries where either of the date is not null. Also, as asked in question, it will not return when all the dates are not null.

Comment: Thanks! I want to select the whole table so should i use "SELECT * from table name" at the begining. But this does not seem to work.

Comment: @pran86 what is the issue that you are facing using Select *

Comment: thanks but need to identify the ones that are not filled in when one of these is filled.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where not ((start_date is not null and middle_date is not null or end_date and not null) or 
           (start_date is null and middle_date is null and end_date is null)
          )
```

This is pretty much a direct translation of your conditions into a `where` conditions.